# Cap Deploy Issues with Rails 3.1.1 and Site5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capistrano

I have a Rails 3.1.1 app that I am trying to deploy via Capistrano.  This is my first attempt at this and I have worked through several issues by doing a lot of research, but I have hit a wall that I can not figure out a way to scale.

I can run cap deploy:setup and cap deploy:check without incident.  When I try and run cap deploy this is what I get see bottom (separated text concerning the rake 0.9.2.2 and the failed line at the bottom)

> Aaron-Johnsons-Macbook-Pro:webd2 aaronjohnsonis$ cap deploy   *
>   executing `deploy'   * executing`deploy:update'  ** transaction:
>   start   * executing `deploy:update_code'
>       updating the cached checkout on all servers
>       executing locally: "git ls-remote git@github.com:webdsquared/webd2.git master"
>       command finished in 2351ms   * executing "if [ -d /home/webdsqua/apps/webd2/shared/cached-copy ]; then cd
>   /home/webdsqua/apps/webd2/shared/cached-copy && git fetch  origin &&
>   git fetch --tags  origin && git reset  --hard
>   28e67c5f7e1ed4612dffd2ac4fb287356f51ce3b && git submodule  init && for
>   mod in`git submodule status | awk '{ print $2 }'`; do git config -f
>   .git/config submodule.${mod}.url`git config -f .gitmodules --get
>   submodule.${mod}.url`&& echo Synced $mod; done && git submodule  sync
>   && export GIT_RECURSIVE=$([ ! \"`git --version`\" \\< \"git version
>   1.6.5\" ] && echo --recursive) && git submodule  update --init $GIT_RECURSIVE && git clean  -d -x -f; else git clone --depth 1
>   git@github.com:webdsquared/webd2.git
>   /home/webdsqua/apps/webd2/shared/cached-copy && cd
>   /home/webdsqua/apps/webd2/shared/cached-copy && git checkout -b deploy
>   28e67c5f7e1ed4612dffd2ac4fb287356f51ce3b && git submodule init && git
>   submodule sync && export GIT_RECURSIVE=$([ ! \"`git --version`\" \\<
>   \"git version 1.6.5\" ] && echo --recursive) && git submodule update
>   --init $GIT_RECURSIVE; fi"
>       servers: ["webdsquared.com"] Password: 
>       [webdsquared.com] executing command  ** [webdsquared.com :: out] HEAD is now at 28e67c5 initial commit
>       command finished in 2428ms
>       copying the cached version to /home/webdsqua/apps/webd2/releases/20111104183017   * executing "cp
>   -RPp /home/webdsqua/apps/webd2/shared/cached-copy /home/webdsqua/apps/webd2/releases/20111104183017 && (echo
>   28e67c5f7e1ed4612dffd2ac4fb287356f51ce3b >
>   /home/webdsqua/apps/webd2/releases/20111104183017/REVISION)"
>       servers: ["webdsquared.com"]
>       [webdsquared.com] executing command
>       command finished in 2997ms   * executing`deploy:finalize_update'
>       triggering before callbacks for `deploy:finalize_update'   * executing`deploy:assets:symlink'   * executing "rm -rf
>   /home/webdsqua/apps/webd2/releases/20111104183017/public/assets &&\\n
>   mkdir -p /home/webdsqua/apps/webd2/releases/20111104183017/public
>   &&\\n        mkdir -p /home/webdsqua/apps/webd2/shared/assets &&\\n 
>   ln -s /home/webdsqua/apps/webd2/shared/assets
>   /home/webdsqua/apps/webd2/releases/20111104183017/public/assets"
>       servers: ["webdsquared.com"]
>       [webdsquared.com] executing command
>       command finished in 1104ms   * executing "chmod -R g+w /home/webdsqua/apps/webd2/releases/20111104183017"
>       servers: ["webdsquared.com"]
>       [webdsquared.com] executing command
>       command finished in 119ms   * executing "rm -rf /home/webdsqua/apps/webd2/releases/20111104183017/log
>   /home/webdsqua/apps/webd2/releases/20111104183017/public/system
>   /home/webdsqua/apps/webd2/releases/20111104183017/tmp/pids &&\\n
>   mkdir -p /home/webdsqua/apps/webd2/releases/20111104183017/public
>   &&\\n      mkdir -p
>   /home/webdsqua/apps/webd2/releases/20111104183017/tmp &&\\n      ln
>   -s /home/webdsqua/apps/webd2/shared/log /home/webdsqua/apps/webd2/releases/20111104183017/log &&\\n      ln
>   -s /home/webdsqua/apps/webd2/shared/system /home/webdsqua/apps/webd2/releases/20111104183017/public/system &&\\n
>   ln -s /home/webdsqua/apps/webd2/shared/pids
>   /home/webdsqua/apps/webd2/releases/20111104183017/tmp/pids"
>       servers: ["webdsquared.com"]
>       [webdsquared.com] executing command
>       command finished in 3136ms
>       triggering after callbacks for `deploy:update_code'   * executing`deploy:assets:precompile'   *** executing "cd
>   /home/webdsqua/apps/webd2/releases/20111104183017 && rake
>   RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets assets:precompile"
>       servers: ["webdsquared.com"]
>       [webdsquared.com] executing command
>
> ** [out :: webdsquared.com] (in /home/webdsqua/apps/webd2/releases/20111104183017)  ** [out >::
>   webdsquared.com] Could not find rake-0.9.2.2 in any of the sources
>       command finished in 1108ms
>   *** [deploy:update_code] rolling back   * executing "rm -rf /home/webdsqua/apps/webd2/releases/20111104183017; true"
>       servers: ["webdsquared.com"]
>       [webdsquared.com] executing command
>       **command finished in 113ms failed: "sh -c 'cd /home/webdsqua/apps/webd2/releases/20111104183017 && rake
>   RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets assets:precompile'" on
>   webdsquared.com****

My deploy.rb file looks like this...

```
set :application, "app"
set :repository, "git@github.com:webdsquared/app.git"

set :scm, "git"
set :deploy_to, "/home/username/apps/#{application}"

set :user, "username"
set :use_sudo, false
set :deploy_via, :remote_cache
set :keep_releases, 3
set :normalize_asset_timestamps, false
set :git_enable_submodules, 1
set :branch, "master"
set :git_shallow_clone, 1
set :scm_verbose, true

role :web, "webdsquared.com"                         
role :app, "webdsquared.com"                          
role :db,  "webdsquared.com", :primary => true                      

after "deploy", "deploy:restart"

namespace :deploy do
  task :start do ; end
  task :stop do ; end
  task :restart, :roles => :app, :except => { :no_release => true } do
    run "touch #{File.join(current_path,'tmp','restart.txt')}"
  end
end
```

The Capfile looks like this...

```
load 'deploy' if respond_to?(:namespace) # cap2 differentiator

Dir['vendor/gems/*/recipes/*.rb','vendor/plugins/*/recipes/*.rb'].each { |plugin| load(plugin) }

load 'config/deploy' # remove this line to skip loading any of the default tasks
```

Any advice would be most appreciated.  Has anyone experienced the same thing and found a solution?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

What version of capistrano are you running? Are you using bundler in your application? The problem is that capistrano is not using `bundle exec` when running commands... It should be running `bundle exec rake...` not just `rake...`